# Android - PreferenceActivity - notifying invoking activity of changes - best practice

Tags: android, android-activity

What's considered best practise for notifying the main Activity of one or more sharedPreferences  changes in an invoked PreferenceActivity ?

Is it to create a specific interface between the two activities, or should the main process have it's own OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, a singleton be used to flag something has changed, something else ?

Answer (score 0):

I use BroadcastReciever for it. In OnRecieve do what need when prefs changed.
Don't need always check flags.

Comment: How does that work as i thought it was best practise to unregister the receiver onPause(), and only re-register it onResume() ? So it won't be around while the preference activity is accepting updates in the foreground, same applies to onPreferenceChange listeners.

Comment: @arober11, unregister on onPause() it's best practice if reciever work with UI. Not all reciever works with UI. Some of my recievers do background job silently when they cath message.

Comment: If you assume the preference activity has been started in response to an ActionBar press is a broadcast receiver still the best way to go. As it will be in a background process at the time the user is playing and  subject to the possibly of being GC'ed?

Comment: At background process, I did not mean something heavy. If you want to do something resource-intensive, you can use the thread running from OnRecieve(), for example. I send broadcast when prefs activity is closed and prefs saved to file. If I need do something I do it in OnRecieve(). Why you think it's may GC'ed?

Comment: Background processes have a lower priority than either foreground, or services and as i understand it are the first to be GC'ed.

Comment: For example my config reciever just do: PackageManager pm = localContext.getPackageManager();ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(localContext, OnBoot.class);  pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(compName, pmFlag, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP); It's all in main thread and in UI process. I don't think GC interesting this. Different tasks - different solutions. When I say "background" I mean tasks that not communicate with user. Sometimes reciever send notification to user if it needed.